# How do I mark a reminder as completed when Item is deleted in my Application?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, xcode11

I have a list of items which are also saved in the native Reminders App and a function which marks the Reminder as completed if they are deleted.

The problem is when I delete an item, the App crashes and I do not know why.
I would be very happy if anyone can help.

List:

```
List{
                ForEach(self.todoVM.todos, id: \.self ){todo in
                    ToDoItemView(todo: todo)
                }.onDelete{indexSet in
                    self.todoVM.deleteTodo(todoIndex: indexSet.first ?? Int())
                    let store = self.eventStore
                    let todoItem = ToDoItem(context: self.context)
                    self.todoVM.complete(store.calendarItem(withIdentifier: todoItem.reminderidentifier ?? String()) as! EKReminder)
                }

                }
```

functions:

```
func Reminders(title: String, notes: String, alarmTime: Date) {
        let todoItem = ToDoItem(context: context)
        let store = self.eventStore
        var identifier:String?
        self.eventStore.requestAccess(to: EKEntityType.reminder, completion: {
         granted, error in
         if (granted) && (error == nil) {
           print("granted \(granted)")


            let reminder:EKReminder = EKReminder(eventStore: self.eventStore)
            reminder.title = title
            //reminder.priority = Int(truncating: NSNumber(value: self.prioritized))
            //reminder.isCompleted = true

            reminder.notes = notes


            let alarmTime = alarmTime
           let alarm = EKAlarm(absoluteDate: alarmTime)
           reminder.addAlarm(alarm)

           reminder.calendar = self.eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewReminders()
            do {
             try self.eventStore.save(reminder, commit: true)
                identifier = reminder.calendarItemIdentifier 
                todoItem.reminderidentifier = identifier
           } catch {
             print("Cannot save")
             return
           }
           print("Reminder saved")
         }else{

            }
        })
    }
    func complete(_ reminder: EKReminder){
        reminder.isCompleted = true
        do {
          try self.eventStore.save(reminder, commit: true)
        } catch {
          print("Cannot save")
          return
        }
    }
```

Comment: What error message do you get on the crash?

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Okay.. that is a good message and can be debugged very easy often. Which line is it? Is it above?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It is here: `self.todoVM.complete(store.calendarItem(withIdentifier: todoItem.reminderidentifier ?? String()) as! EKReminder)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error you get, you are unwrapping something which is nil

```
let todoItem = ToDoItem(context: self.context)

self.todoVM.complete(store.calendarItem(withIdentifier: todoItem.reminderidentifier ?? String()) as! EKReminder)
```

The problem lays here..  you are searching with an Identifier, which might not be set. (Where do you set `todoItem.reminderidentifier` after creating the object?)

If it is not set, you are using a empty String with `String()`. Forcing to unwrap it to a EKReminder won't work. You need to handle it differently.